# Is it spam to ask in other venues?

Tags: discussion

In an answer to [Useful mathematical fora](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95787/useful-mathematical-fora) there is a rather long list of venues where we can ask math questions not answered on math.SE.

My question: is it spam to ask questions there after already asked in math.SE?

For example, I've asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689866/three-definition-of-total-boundness-for-uniform-spaces). Is it good:

1. to ask it on "Ask a Topologist" after some time not answered at math.SE?
2. to ask it on "Ask a Topologist" not waiting for a reply at math.SE? (immediately now)

Comment: I would consider it bad form to ask the same question in two places at the same time. Remember that the populations of these two websites most probably have non-trivial intersection. It is better leaving it for a day or two (I would go for a minimum of three, but then again I am never in a hurry).

Comment: You can find some older related discussions if you have a look at the questions tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]).

Comment: More important than time interval is the existence of cross-links between questions. If I see such a link, I'll check whether the question is already answered on the other site before spending time on it. Otherwise, if I spend time answering and later find out that I only duplicated an answer on the other site... I will not be amused.

Comment: When you decide to cook supper, do you use **all** the available resources you have, or do you prepare one meal, eat it and the next day eat another?

Comment: Bad form, yes.  Spam, no.  "Spam" has a rather more technical meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Asking in several places will usually not be considered spam (as that means something else).

In general, it is fine to ask other places after not getting an answer for a while, but it is good form to make sure that all the places you ask, you also mention all the other places, in order to avoid duplicate effort (and preferably also update all the places once you have an answer in one of them).